# Allocation of buffer in C

Tags: c, buffer, allocation

I am trying to create buffer to store infinity size of symbols.

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct buffer {  
    int bufferSize;  
    int literalSize;  
    int allocatedSize;  
    char *bufferPtr;  
} bufferStruct;
```

In my **file.h**.

I have also functions for buffer:

```
bufferStruct *BufferInitialize(int size) {
    bufferStruct *tempBuff;
    tempBuff = (bufferStruct *)malloc(sizeof(bufferStruct));
    if (tempBuff == NULL) {
        exit(99);       // MEMORY_ERROR
    }
    tempBuff->bufferSize = size;
    tempBuff->literalSize = 0;
    tempBuff->bufferPtr = NULL;
    tempBuff->allocatedSize = 0;

    return (tempBuff);
}

int addToBuffer(bufferStruct *buffer, char c) {
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        return 99;      // MEMORY_ERROR
    }
    if (buffer->allocatedSize > buffer->literalSize) {
        buffer->bufferPtr[buffer->literalSize++] = c;
    } else {
        buffer->bufferPtr = realloc(buffer->bufferPtr, (buffer->allocatedSize + buffer->bufferSize) * sizeof(char));
        if (buffer->bufferPtr == NULL) {
            return 99;      // MEMORY_ERROR
        }
        buffer->allocatedSize += buffer->bufferSize;
        buffer->bufferSize <<= 1;   // bS = bS * 2
        buffer->bufferPtr[buffer->literalSize++] = c;
    }
    return 0;
}

int bufferDestroy(bufferStruct *buffer) {
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        return 99;      // MEMORY_ERROR
    }
    free(buffer->bufferPtr);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

In my **file.c** I am trying to create buffer:

```
 token *getNextToken(token *tokenT) {
    token *actualToken = NULL;
    char *bufferData = NULL;
    int charFromFile;
    eState state = stateInit;

    bufferStruct *bufferT = NULL;

    while ((charFromFile = fgetc(fp))) {                
        switch (state) {
          case stateInit: {
                if (isdigit(charFromFile)) {
                    bufferT = BufferInitialize(8);
                    addToBuffer(bufferT, charFromFile);
                    state = stateInt;
                } else
                if (isalpha(charFromFile) || (charFromFile == '_')) {
                    state = stateId;
                    bufferT = BufferInitialize(16);
                    addToBuffer(bufferT, charFromFile);
                } else
                if (isspace(charFromFile)) {
                    state = stateInit;

                ... some more conditions ... it's similar, a lot.

          case stateInt: {
                if (isdigit(charFromFile)) {
                    state = stateInt;
                    addToBuffer(bufferT, charFromFile);
                } else
                if ((charFromFile == 'e') || (charFromFile == 'E')) {
                    state = stateExp;
                    addToBuffer(bufferT, charFromFile);
                } else
                if (charFromFile = '.') {
                    state = stateDouble;
                    addToBuffer(bufferT, charFromFile);
                } else {
                    bufferData = bufferT->bufferPtr;
                    //strcpy(actualToken->content, bufferData);
                    addToBuffer(bufferT, '\0');
                    bufferDestroy(bufferT);
                    actualToken->type = tokenInt;
                    return actualToken;
                }
            } break;

               ... other similar cases ... 
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I am trying to do this, Visual studio give me error:

> `One or more multiply defined symbols found`
>   Also gives me 
>   `already defined in main.obj`
>   for every function I have.

I don't see the way out. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is there some defined data in the header file? And btw when you define your struct, no need to put buffer after the struct keyword.

Comment: Add an initialization to the declaration: `bufferStruct * buffer = NULL;`

Comment: Post complete code, please.

Comment: I guess I can leave the word. I can't initialize .. gives me second error. The code is long, thats why I cut it.

Comment: I posted more code.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- You should not put code in header files.  The function `BufferInitialize` should not be located in `file.h` unless it is defined `inline`.
- The test `while (c = fgetc(fp))` is incorrect:  you use an assignment as a test expression, it is very error prone, you should at least parenthesize the assignment expression, and probably test for `EOF` instead of `'\0'`:  `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)`.  Furthermore, `c` must be defined as an `int`.  Post actual code, not pseudo-code.
- You initialize `tempBuff->bufferSize` to a potentially non zero value, whereas the `allocatedSize` is `0` and the buffer is unallocated.  This seems incorrect.

There could be many more issues in your actual code, we cannot see what the code, how can be tell you about those?  Always post a complete, compilable code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I moved declaration of functions to '.c file'. The while condition is correct in my code. I also can't check for EOF cause I need to continue behind EOF. I believe that there is more errors than I can see, but I just started. Unfortunatelly I got stucked at this buffer error.

Comment: You must learn the difference between a **declaration** such as `extern token *getNextToken(token *tokenT);` that belongs in a header file (**.h** extension) and tells your compiler how the function is *defined* in another module, and a **definition** such as `token *getNextToken(token *tokenT) { /* some code */ return NULL; }` that belongs in a C source file (**.c** extension) and must not be duplicated in the same file or in different files.

Comment: I know that and I don't have any duplications. I was just confused a little bit about function of buffer so I was trying things.